# Create View for ViewModel post returns ViewModel with empty foreign key properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, post, mvvm, viewmodel

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC3 (my first) mean to track data processing steps for the engineering firm where I work.

Below are some of the domain models:

**Dataset:**

```
Partial Public MustInherit Class Dataset
    Public Property DatasetID As System.Guid
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overridable Property ProcessDatasets As ICollection(Of ProcessDataset) = New HashSet(Of ProcessDataset)
    Public Overridable Property DeliveryBatches As ICollection(Of DeliveryBatch) = New HashSet(Of DeliveryBatch)

End Class
```

**Process:**

```
Partial Public Class Process
    Public Property ProcessID As System.Guid
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property SOP As String
    Public Property ProcessOrder As Nullable(Of Integer)

    Public Overridable Property ProcessDatasets As ICollection(Of ProcessDataset) = New HashSet(Of ProcessDataset)

End Class
```

**ProcessDataset:** (attributed join table)

```
Partial Public Class ProcessDataset
    Public Property ProcessID As System.Guid
    Public Property DatasetID As System.Guid
    Public Property OwnerID As Nullable(Of System.Guid)
    Public Property Started As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property Completed As Nullable(Of Date)

    Public Overridable Property Dataset As Dataset
    Public Overridable Property Process As Process
    Public Overridable Property ProcessOwner As ProcessOwner

End Class
```

My goal is to select 1 or many Datasets from the Index or Details view of Dataset (using the domain model) and click a link to `Add New Process to Dataset(s)` which will open this desired Create view.  Any ProcessDatasets created by the Create view will automatically reference the selected Datasets without the user having to select them from a list.

Below is the ViewModel I created for ProcessDataset.

**ProcessStatusDataset:**

```
Public Class ProcessStatusDataset

    Public Property ProcessDataset As ProcessDataset
    Public Property Datasets As IEnumerable(Of Dataset)

End Class
```

**Controller Methods in ProcessDatasetController:**

```
'
' GET: /ProcessDataset/Create

Function CreateProcessStatus(id As Guid) As ViewResult
    Dim processStatus As New ProcessStatusDataset
    processStatus.Datasets = db.Datasets.Where(Function(d) d.DatasetID = id)
    ViewBag.ProcessID = New SelectList(db.Processes, "ProcessID", "Name")
    ViewBag.OwnerID = New SelectList(db.ProcessOwners, "ProcessOwnerID", "Name")
    Return View(processStatus)
End Function

'
' POST: /ProcessDataset/Create

<HttpPost()>
Function CreateProcessStatus(processstatusdataset As ProcessStatusDataset) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        For Each dataset In processstatusdataset.Datasets
            Dim processdataset As New ProcessDataset
            processdataset.ProcessID = processstatusdataset.ProcessDataset.ProcessID
            processdataset.OwnerID = processstatusdataset.ProcessDataset.OwnerID
            processdataset.Completed = processstatusdataset.ProcessDataset.Completed
            processdataset.Started = processstatusdataset.ProcessDataset.Started
            processdataset.DatasetID = dataset.DatasetID
            db.ProcessDatasets.Add(processdataset)
        Next
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End If

    ViewBag.ProcessID = New SelectList(db.Processes, "ProcessID", "Name", processstatusdataset.ProcessDataset.ProcessID)
    ViewBag.OwnerID = New SelectList(db.ProcessOwners, "ProcessOwnerID", "Name", processstatusdataset.ProcessDataset.OwnerID)
    Return View(processstatusdataset)
```

**CreateProcessStatus View:**

```
@ModelType ProductionDataTrackingMVC.ProcessStatusDataset
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Add New Process to Datasets"
End Code
<h2>
    Add New Process to Datasets</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@Using Html.BeginForm("CreateProcessStatus","ProcessDataset")
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)
    @<fieldset>
        <legend>Process Status</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelForPascalCase(Function(model) model.ProcessDataset.Process):
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProcessID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ProcessDataset.ProcessID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelForPascalCase(Function(model) model.ProcessDataset.ProcessOwner):
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("OwnerID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ProcessDataset.OwnerID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelForPascalCase(Function(model) model.ProcessDataset.Started):
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.ProcessDataset.Started)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ProcessDataset.Started)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelForPascalCase(Function(model) model.ProcessDataset.Completed):
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.ProcessDataset.Completed)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ProcessDataset.Completed)
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Dataset Type
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.LabelForPascalCase(Function(model) model.Datasets.FirstOrDefault().Name)
                    </th>
                </tr>
    @For Each item In Model.Datasets
        Dim currentItem = item
                @<tr>
                    <td>
                        @currentItem.GetType().BaseType.Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
    Next
            </table>
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add New Process Status" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
End Using
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Process Status Datasets List", "Index")
</div>
```

At this point, the `ProcessStatusDataset` passed into the `CreateProcessStatus` POST method always comes in with blank Guids where there should be an ID for `Process` and `Owner`.  The `Datasets` property is also `Nothing`.

When I look at the source of the rendered page I see:

```
<form action="/ProcessDataset/CreateProcessStatus/e29bc119-b8c2-4ac5-9ce7-c9780673c193" method="post">
```

Where the Guid on the end of the link is the ID of the single `Dataset` selected in the `Dataset` Details view.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.  I've been searching Google with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dropdowns**

I don't think this will work:

...

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProcessID", String.Empty)
```

...

Instead, you should try something like this:

...

```
@{
    Dim processes = DirectCast(ViewBag.Processes, SelectList);
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.ProcessDataset.ProcessId, processes, "Select Process")
```

...

```
'remember to set this on the post too, in case of returning the same view.
ViewBag.Processes = New SelectList(db.Processes, "ProcessID", "Name")
```

...

That should let **model binder** (you might want to google this concept if you don't know it) to do its magic. Otherwise just change the returning type of `HttpPost` action method to `FormCollection` and inspect the keys to check what are you bringing back from your post.

**Datasets issue**

I don't think you are setting any html form field to expect to see something back in your Post.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are suggesting here.  What do you mean in your Datasets issue section of your answer?

Comment: You said that in your post action `Datasets` property is `Nothing`, well that's becuase there isn't any field that stores such information in your html form. Did you check the `FormCollection` approach I mentioned, that might help to understand what's going on with the post results.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  I assumed that because I was passing a model into the view that had datasets, the view would pass the same model back with added data.  It appears that the view creates a new model to pass back?  How would I go about making the datasets stay with the model that gets posted back to the controller?  By the way, your drop down suggestion worked, thank you.

Comment: In your case scenario, I would set a hidden input with the DatasetId, since it's the only property you seem to need on your post. If you code it right, it should be just one line on your view that adds the the hidden field and your Post Action should work as it is now. I leave that to you bro, you're close! Read about **model binder** too, it's important.